# How to sort datatable by column with datetime datatype

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datatable

What i have done is as below

```
dtClaim.DefaultView.Sort = "TransactionDate asc";
dtClaim = dtClaim.DefaultView.ToTable();
ViewState["dtClaim"] = dtClaim;
```

Here is a screen shot of data of data table before applying a sorting

[image: sort]

But also after using above code i am not able to sort data by using "TransactionDate"

**Edit**

Here i shown that how i am preparing this datatable

```
 DataTable dtClaim = new DataTable();
 dtClaim = (DataTable)ViewState["dtClaim"];

 DataRow drClaim = dtClaim.NewRow();
 drClaim["ClaimId"] = count + 1;
 drClaim["TextileClaimApplicationId"] = ViewState["TextileClaimApplicationId"].ToString();
 drClaim["BankId"] = ViewState["TextileClaimApplicationId"].ToString();
 drClaim["BankName"] = ViewState["TextileClaimApplicationId"].ToString();
 drClaim["SectorId"] = ViewState["TextileClaimApplicationId"].ToString();
 drClaim["IsDisbursment"] = rblIsDisbursment.SelectedValue;
 drClaim["TransactionDate"] = txtDisbursementDate.Text == "" ? Convert.ToDateTime(txtRepaymentDate.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat) : Convert.ToDateTime(txtDisbursementDate.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat);
 drClaim["DisbursementAmount"] = txtDisbursementAmount.Text == "" ? Convert.ToDecimal("0") : Convert.ToDecimal(txtDisbursementAmount.Text);
 drClaim["RepaymentPrincipleAmount"] = txtRepaymentPrincipleAmount.Text == "" ? Convert.ToDecimal("0") : Convert.ToDecimal(txtRepaymentPrincipleAmount.Text);
 drClaim["RepaymentOtherAmount"] = txtRepaymentOtherAmount.Text == "" ? Convert.ToDecimal("0") : Convert.ToDecimal(txtRepaymentOtherAmount.Text);
 dtClaim.Rows.Add(drClaim);



dtClaim.DefaultView.Sort = "TransactionDate";
dtClaim = dtClaim.DefaultView.ToTable();
ViewState["dtClaim"] = dtClaim;
```

Comment: The sort is working fine - i think its a binding issue.

Comment: after applying above sorting logic, i tried to see data in Quick watch but there was no any sorted data. It was same as before..

Comment: Works fine for me - may be your compiler's broken -http://postimg.org/image/8braslgrn/

Comment: Please find updated question..

Comment: Found problem....Datatable is considering "TransactionDate" as string because i didn't specify datatype for it. i have just defined datatype and it is working like superman.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get my code to recognize a DataTable value as a DateTime I had to set the data type of my row when I created it. (I was using this DataTable as a DataSource for my GridView and was having difficulties getting it to sort on it.)

previously I had

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("StartDate");
```

I changed this to

```
dt.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

Changing the type I was inserting into that column to a DateTime did not work until I set the column type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.110).aspx